# Flag match with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have some flag strings like '-s' or '-r', how can I match only and only the '-s' flag, excluding matches like '-solve' or 're-solve' , with regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```js
const exp = /(^|\s)\-s($|\s)/
const testCases = ["-s", "-solve", "re-solve"]
testCases.forEach(e => console.log(e, exp.test(e)))
```

Basically, the regex look for the `-s` string that is preceded by the start of the string or a space and is fallowed by the end of the string or a space.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it. starting and ending spaces handled.

`\S*-s\b`

Answer (score 0):

Try the regex `/^-(s|r)$/g` when you put your flag letters instead of `s|r`. Then you can get the selected letter, as follows:

```
var flag = /^-(s|r)$/g.exec(text)[1];
```